# Bind ObjectDataSource to Webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services

Is this possible, does anyone know of any good examples

Answer (score 0):

You probably need some kind of data access class which holds a reference to the result of the webservice call and do your databinding on that property.

Answer (score 0):

ObjectDataSource requires any particular Object which exposes atleast one of four basic methods to INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE and SELECT.

You need wrap-around the Web service results within a Class. You cannot directly bind the Webservice with ObjectDataSource.